# How to integrate LUIS to a QnA bot Azure

Tags: c#, bots, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service

So I was recently tinkering with Azure Bot Services and Q&A but I noticed it didn't answer everything correctly and didn't get the intent sometimes so I decided to add LUIS to it but I don't really get how to integrate it to the bot. (They give a code sample but I don't really know where to put it).

I also wanted to know if there's a way for me to change the Q&A bot's language from English to French because most of my customers are French.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See another sample here to use QnA+LUIS together: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/tree/master/Node/samples

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this sample: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/intelligence-LUIS